# Using variables in JSTL param

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Is there any way to specify a variable as a parameter name in JSTL, i.e:

```
<c:set var='myVar' value='dynamicParameterName' />

<c:out value='${param.(dynamicParameterName)}' />
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`${param.myVar}` or `${param[myVar]}` are equivalent.

Comment: The first one doesn't work in this particular case as `myVar` is at its own a variable. The second one (the so called brace notation) is indeed the way to go.